# Stuttering movement in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So basically I am trying to make player movement system like one in RPG Maker with 8 directions. Somehow I succeded, but only partially. When I am trying to suddenly change direction for ex. from up to left, character stutter and do not want to move without releasing all keys first.

Gravity scale is disabled or more like set to 0, body type is dynamic.

Here is a code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveChar : MonoBehaviour {

Rigidbody2D rigid;

public float Speed;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

//        float horiz = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

//        float vert = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) //________________________________________MOVING UP

    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(rigid.velocity.x, 1 * Speed);
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) //_______________________________________MOVING DOWN
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(rigid.velocity.x, -1 * Speed);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }


    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) //_______________________________________MOVING LEFT
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(-1 * Speed, rigid.velocity.y);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) //_______________________________________MOVING RIGHT
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(1 * Speed, rigid.velocity.y);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to stop setting your velocity to zero every time a key is lifted up. You only want to modify one component of the vector in that case, and also you need to consider the state of the key for going in the opposite direction.  Also, is there a reason you aren't using `Input.GetAxis`? It does a lot of the stuff you're trying to do here.

Comment: As Ruzihm says the first thing I would try is instead of setting `(0,0)` only change `x` **or** `y` the respective one you change in the other case of if.

Comment: There is no reason for not using Axis, I simply don't know hot to use it. I tried using it before, but I could not implement it as negative value (even if I tried putting '-' before it, it did not work for some reasons). When i will not set value to 0, 0 after lifting key up, character will fly at set direction, I do not know any other way to stop it.

Comment: @lubeszz I edited my answer to include how to use `Input.GetKeyUp/GetKeyDown` if you must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Input.GetAxis(axisName)` to avoid conflicting cases in your input code. Also, use AddForce to play nicely with other rigidbodies.

```
Vector2 oldV = rigid.velocity;
float horiz = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float vert = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

Vector2 newV = new Vector2(horiz * Speed, vert * Speed);
rigid.AddForce(newV-oldV, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Alternatively, keep track of your own axes when keys are lifted/pressed down

```
public float horiz;
public float vert;

void Start() {
    horiz = 0f;
    vert = 0f;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) horiz -= 1f;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) horiz += 1f;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) vert -= 1f;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) vert += 1f;
}

void Update () {
    Vector2 oldV = rigid.velocity;

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) vert += 1f;
    else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W)) vert -= 1f;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) vert -= 1f;
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S)) vert += 1f;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) horiz -= 1f;
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)) horiz += 1f;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) horiz += 1f;
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)) horiz -= 1f;

    Vector2 newV = new Vector2(horiz * Speed, vert * Speed);
    rigid.AddForce(newV-oldV, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: If this most helped answer your question, please mark it as the selected answer by clicking on the grey check mark under the voting buttons. This will help people with similar problems find this answer in the future. It will also give me some Stack Overflow points ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is only a small problem with releasing the button. Add the original force in the direction that is not affected by the key. The whole script should look like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) //________________________________________MOVING UP
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(rigid.velocity.x, 1 * Speed);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(rigid.velocity.x, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) //_______________________________________MOVING DOWN
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(rigid.velocity.x, -1 * Speed);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(rigid.velocity.x, 0);
    }


    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) //_______________________________________MOVING LEFT
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(-1 * Speed, rigid.velocity.y);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(0, rigid.velocity.y);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) //_______________________________________MOVING RIGHT
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(1 * Speed, rigid.velocity.y);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
    {
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(0, rigid.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: It helped a bit, but there still are some stutters

Comment: Additional: Change Interpolate parameter of rigidbody component to "Interpolate"

Comment: If you press both A and D then only release D, this code won't move the body horizontally at all.

Comment: I was not sure if that was wanted @Ruzihm